# Authorization - Create and unlock a User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I just wrote this, but I am not realy happy with that. I think there is an easier way to do this. First I am checking if a user has an ID (from a portal we are using, it is in the header). After that I have to check if the user exists in my application, if not a user will be created, if the user exists, the `datetime lastlogon` will be updated.
(here is my first problem, `CheckIfUserExists` always returns `true`, except on an Exception, is this ok?). After that I am checking if `userExists` is `true`. If a user is created it has to be unblocked by an admin. If this happened the user can access the page.
If the user is in Role Admin, Viewbag is `true` otherwise `false`. If `userExists` is `false`, he is getting the default error.

I think my chain of thought is realy complicated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool userExists = false;
    if (HelperClass.UserId != "")
        userExists = CheckIfUserExists(HelperClass.UserId);
    else
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");

    if (userExists)
    {
        bool unblocked = CheckIfUnblocked(HelperClass.UserId);
        if (unblocked)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                ViewBag.Admin = true;
            else
                ViewBag.Admin = false;
            return View("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding Code

```
public bool CheckIfUserExists(string u_gvid)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_Connection))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                //qry check if user exists
                var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().ToLower();
                if (result == "false")
                {
                    return CreateUser(HelperClass.UserId, HelperClass.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Update lastlogonn time
                    //qry
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
        //log
        RedirectToAction("DatabaseError", "Error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
    return false;
}

public bool CheckIfUnblocked(string u_gvid)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_Connection))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                //qry "SELECT unblocked FROM tbl.users WHERE uid = @uid";
                var result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
        //log
        RedirectToAction("DatabaseError", "Error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Heslacher I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CheckIfUserExists()**

Well this method doesn't do what its name implies. You should either rename it or you only should check if the user exists. Because this method is `public` it should validate the method parameters.

---

If we assume you have changed the way `CheckIfUserExists()` works your code could look like so

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HelperClass.UserId)) { return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error"); }
    if (!CheckIfUserExists(HelperClass.UserId) && !CreateUser(HelperClass.UserId, HelperClass.Name))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    if (!CheckIfUnblocked(HelperClass.UserId)) { return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error"); }

    ViewBag.Admin = User.IsInRole("Admin");

    return View("Index");
}
```

I refactored the code by

- using guard conditions to return early which saves some indentation
- assigning the return value of a `bool` method directly to a `bool` variable

Comment: Ty, but in `CheckIfUserExists()` I am checking with a qry statement if an user exists, if not `CreateUser()` will be called?

Comment: Thats why I wrote "If we assume you have changed the way CheckIfUserExists() works" which is what I suggest you should do.

Comment: Okay, so it should only check if a user exists and nothing else, ty.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick remarks:

- Don't name things "class", e.g. `HelperClass`.
- Don't use Hungarian notation and give your variables meaningful names: `u_gvid` is a complete mystery to me.
- I don't get why `CheckIfUserExists` and `CheckIfUnblocked` are `public`, and even less why they'd use `RedirectToAction`. I expect these methods to return a boolean, not to execute redirects etc.
- `NpgsqlConnection` and `NpgsqlCommand` don't follow the Microsoft naming guidelines: they are compound words, so the "s" in "sql" should be capitalized.
- Don't write ADO.NET code. You're using 15+ lines to write something that could be expressed much simpler by using Dapper. The `var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().ToLower();` and `if (result == "false")` bit is even worse. You don't provide us with the relevant SQL, so perhaps there is a good reason to return a boolean-like string, but I wouldn't be surprised if the query logic could be much simplified.
- `CheckIfUserExists` and `CheckIfUnblocked` are IMHO bad method names. To me they should be something like `DoesUserExist` and `IsUserUnblocked`, which are the kind of methods I'd expect to return a boolean.
- `CheckIfUserExists` should not execute `CreateUser`, unless you rename the method. And I wouldn't expect a method called `CreateUser` to return a boolean. Avoid this temptation by moving these methods to a service etc. instead of them being part of the controller. Keep your controllers as light as possible, things like data processing etc. should be handled by dedicated classes.
- In `CheckIfUnblocked` you have a boolean: `var result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`. Why then not simply return this instead of doing the whole `if (result) return true;` / `else return false;` dance? You spend six lines on something that could be expressed by a single one.

Comment: Ty for all those hints and tipps! :)  Hungarian notation: So instead of userExists i should use userexists? And CheckIfUnblocked would be checkifunblocked? For me the hungarian notation (didn't know about that) is easier to read?

Comment: @SpedoDeLaRossa This is Hungarian notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation Which you should **not** use. Please read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions and other pages in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines WRT naming standard etc.

Comment: When you don't expect those methods to redirect to anywhere (example: in the exceptions) then I would have a try catch in the Index method? So in this case, i should only redirect in the Index action?

Comment: @SpedoDeLaRossa IMHO: yes. Otherwise you're starting to mix presentation and business logic. Also, avoid using exceptions to implement logic. There's really no reason to expect any exception in for instance the user check method. Yes, `ExecuteScalar` can cause an exception in your code when it returns `null`, but that's *not an exception*, but something your code should handle (and not by using a `try ... catch` block).